# Derivation of constant $\gamma$ in a magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism

So, I'm trying to prove that $\frac{d\gamma}{dt} = 0$ in the case of a relativistic charged particle moving in a field with $E = 0, B \ne 0$.

Using the normal relativistic Lagrangian I come to:

$\frac{d}{dt}(\gamma m \underline{v}) = e\underline{v} \ \times \ \underline{B} \\ 
\underline{v} \ \cdot \ \frac{d}{dt}(\gamma m \underline{v}) = 0 $

Apparently I should be able to see that:

$\underline{v} \ \cdot \ \frac{d}{dt}(\gamma m \underline{v}) = mc^2\frac{d\gamma}{dt}$

However I'm more than a little rusty when it comes to relativity. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ...in other words to prove the well-known result that a magnetic field doesn't change the magnitude of the velocity of a charged particle, only its direction.

Comment: Yes, but it's the specific expression that I'm curious about.

Comment: Please don't forget that you could upvote and/or accept as best an answer that satisfies you, if any. Isn't @Mark H's a candidate one ???

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say that your last equation is something one can just see intuitively (judging by my page of scratched out math), but here are a couple of hints that are useful for getting from one side to the other.

The derivative of a dot product: $\frac{d}{dt}(\underline{a}\cdot\underline{b}) = \underline{a}\cdot\frac{d\underline{b}}{dt} + \frac{d\underline{a}}{dt}\cdot\underline{b}$. If you use $\underline{a} =\underline{v}$ and $\underline{b} = \underline{v}$, you'll find a way to simplify $\underline{v}\cdot\frac{d\underline{v}}{dt}$ to a scalar expression (keeping in mind that $v = |\underline{v}|$).

Find $\frac{d\gamma}{dt}$ in terms of $\frac{dv}{dt}$. Use this after you expand $\frac{d}{dt}(\gamma m \underline{v})$ to get rid of every $\frac{dv}{dt}$ and leave only $\frac{d\gamma}{dt}$.